# How do i compare some letters of text input with mysql database

Tags: php, mysqli, where-clause

I'm trying to find a way to compare some letters of my text input with a column on a MYSQL table. Here's my code:

```
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT nicename, phonecode FROM country.country WHERE phonecode=$ccode");
```

What I want is to compare the first two or three letters from my variable `$ccode` to the `phonecode` from table `country`.

I tried using `$ccode%` like I would do for normal text but it didn't work.

The Database field phonecode contains international phone codes and variable $ccode contains the full number of a person. I have to extract the country code from the variable $ccode and compare it with the database field.

Comment: Can you explain *I tried using '$ccode%' like i would do for normal text but it didn't work*?

Comment: `WHERE phonecode = SUBSTR($ccode,0,2)` wacht out for SQL injections though.

Comment: You are a bit short on details! Can you show examples of the content of the database column `phonecode`and its DataType. And also the content of `$ccode` please

Comment: $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT nicename, phonecode FROM country.country WHERE phonecode=$ccode%");

Comment: <form action="index.php" method="post">
Phone number: <input type="text" name="country" maxlength="4" size="2">
<button type="submit" name="submit" action="submit">
Submit
</button>
</form>
$ccode=$_POST["country"];
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT nicename, phonecode FROM country.country WHERE phonecode=$ccode");

Answer (score 0):

I don't know PHP more but as per C# we need to add dynamically parameter value.

$tempQuery = "SELECT nicename, phonecode FROM country.country WHERE phonecode like ";

SubString of your $ccode and then add into query

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $tempQuery + "'%" + $ccode + "%'");

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUBSTR`

```
$ccode=substr($ccode,0,2); //for two digit, if you want 3 digit replace 2 with 3.

mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT nicename, phonecode FROM country.country
             WHERE phonecode=$ccode");
```